# How to push after making a commit that changes access-restricted files?

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a gitolite repo with the following access rules:

```
repo foo
    RW+                     = admin
    RW+                     = user
    RW+ VREF/NAME/toPush.py = user
    -   VREF/NAME/          = user
```

The foo repo is organized like this:

```
foo
  --toPush.py
  --notToPush.py
```

What I want to do is allow the admin full access to the `foo` repository, but give the user push access to only the `toPush.py` file.

From the user side, this works if I make changes and commit ONLY the `toPush.py` file and push it. If even by accident I commit the `notToPush.py` after making changes and push, it fails (as it should).

My problem is: How do I push the updated `toPush.py` now that I have accidentally committed the `notToPush.py`? I tried to `git rm --cached notToPush.py`, commit the changes and push again but it still fails. I went through gitolite's official documentation, but I don't see anything regarding fixing bad commits and pushes. Does making a single commit on a file that the user does not have push privileges make it so that I can't push at all?

Thanks in advance. I apologize if there is a simple fix, I'm unable to find one.

Comment: Rewrite the commit locally and then push. Undo the change you made to `notToPush.py`, then do a `git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gitolite rule is `RW+`, which means you can do a force push (`git push --force`)

That means you can:

- `git reset @~`, change your files, add, commit, and `git push --force`.
- or modify directly your files, add and, as commented, `git commit --amend --no-edit`